# keypress in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, keypress

I want to control robot with `Visual C++` using `serial port`, if I press 'W' the robot will move forward, press 'S' the robot will move backward. I use `Visual Studio C++` form application. I am newbie in C++ and `WinForm`- application

For the serial connection is fine, but the problem is how can I get the event of the keypress, so I can send the characters to robot?

Answer (score 0):

To Get the keypress / keydown event you should have some edit control in your form application